# php dom parser return parent and child

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I think this is a simple question but I can't sort it, I am trying to get all heading tags with the simple php DOM parser, my code works only one way, example

```
 $heading['h2']=$html->find('h2 a');//works fine
```

I have found some sites wrap the `h2` within the a tag like this

```
<a href='#'><h2> my heading</h2></a>
```

The problem is trying to get both tags so I can display the link with it. So when I do this

```
$heading['h2']=$html->find('a h2');
```

I get the `h2` fine but it will not wrap the link tag around it, which of course makes sense, find all h2 tags that are children of `a` but how do I get the entire parent tag, I hope that makes sense, what I want it to return is

```
<a href="#"><h2>My Headings</h2></a>
```

then I can just print the output with

```
echo $headings['h2']; //and the link with be there
```

Comment: You need to phrase this as a question. For example, your question might be: how do I find all `h2`'s that descend from an `a`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `<a href="[..]">` ist just the outer element, you can do it like this:

```
$heading['h2']=$html->find('a h2');
foreach ($heading['h2'] as $h2) {
    echo $h2->parent(), "\n";
}
```

You could also go up the DOM tree until you reach an `<a>` tag:

```
$heading['h2']=$html->find('a h2');
foreach ($heading['h2'] as $h2) {
    $a = $h2;
    while ($a && $a->tag != "h2") $a = $a->parent();
    if (!$a) continue; // no <a> above <h2>
    echo $a, "\n";
}
```

Comment: thank you this worked echo $h2->parent(),seems so simple when you are shown

Answer (score 0):

Well my first thought we be to use

```
$html->find('a');
```

But I'm guessing you have multiple links on your page. So the correct practice would then be to use an ID (or a class) to identify your link

```
<a href='#' id="titleLink"><h2> my heading</h2></a>
```

And then search for that specific ID:

```
$html->find('a#titleLink');
```

I don't know what library you're using and what syntax it supports, but I hope you get the idea anyway.

Comment: yes that would be ideal but i am not sure what url my page will be fed so it is impossible to know what the id will be, i guess i could assign one but given i need to get all the headings, i.e h1, - h6 it might be a little cumbersome but i will give it some thought, thank you kindly

Answer (score 0):

According to docs: `$heading['h2']=$html->find('a > h2')->parent();` would return the anchor tag wrapping the h2, but if you have multiple 'a > h2' in the page, the find function will return an array, so try it and/or use foreach.

Comment: this makes complete sense but for some reason it doesn't work, perhaps i am making a mistake but thank you, i will continue to play with it

Answer (score 0):

```
$info = $html->find('a,h2');

echo '<a href='.$info[0]->href.'>'.$info[1]->innertext.'</a>';
```